# bluetoothsocket can't connect with remote bluetoothdevice

Tags: android

I'm developing an android aplication, and i try to connect to a other paired device. When I go to connect to the device my Logcat show this warning ***getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback*** and the state of socket is:  ***connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[47]***}. 
Someone can tell me why the socket can not connect to de remote device??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please visit your android sdk there is a sample  Bluetooth chat application  For eg:(adt-bundle-linux-x86-20140702/sdk/samples/android-19/legacy/Bluetooth Chat).Import the project in your work space.
In the sample Project there is a BluetoothChatService.java class.
Please refer to the class it will helps you.